# how to pass body parameters in URL in postman?

Tags: php, json, postman

I am trying to pass raw body data in the POSTMAN URL section. how I can achieve this?
have a look here:
 I have this URL in postman with the "GET" method
    http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/gh/v3/contacts
and I am passing this data in the body

```
{
"query":{
"tags_include" : 92
}
}
```

i have to pass id(92) in the URL of POSTMAN how can i do this?

Comment: simply like this http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/gh/v3/contacts?id=92

Comment: http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/gh/v3/contacts?tags_include=92 this is what i tried but it didn't work because of the data format that is provided is different in the query it includes the tags_include.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done simply by passing parameters just in URL:

http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/gh/v3/contacts?tags_include=92

Comment: i have tried this but it's not working. what about the query present here? {
"query":{
"tags_include" : 92
}
} this "query" doesn't make any sense in the url?

Answer (score 0):

Follow as per below screenshot

[image]

Comment: no it's not working. it returns the entire data just like before nothing happened.

Comment: Could you share any screenshot of reques in POSTMAN?

Answer (score 0):

localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-json/gh/v3/contacts/:{{tags_include}}

If I have understood correctly, you are getting the raw data from some other URL and now you want to pass its "tags_include" parameter value in the URL specified above.

What you need to do is, use the above URL(that I edited) but, for it to work, you need to write the following code in the tests section of postman. Use this code in the test section of the request that responds with the data(that you specified above).

Here is the code:

var body = JSON.parse(response body);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('tags_include', body.query.tags_include);

Comment: i have tried this but in the url it shows "unresolved variable" ?